# Getting attempt to index global ''io'' error while trying to read a file via Tarantool LUA admin console

Tags: lua, tarantool

I've got a question.
Why cannot I get access to a file from Tarantool LUA admin console?
Am I in a jail ?

```
tarantool -h myhost -a 33015
help

console client commands:
- help
- loadfile 'path'
- setopt key=val
- (possible pairs: delimiter = 'string' )
- ( pager = 'command' )
...
---
available commands:
- help
- exit
- show info
- show fiber
- show configuration
- show slab
- show palloc
- show stat
- show plugins
- save coredump
- save snapshot
- lua command
- reload configuration
- show injections (debug mode only)
- set injection <name> <state> (debug mode only)
...


myhost> lua file = io.open("/etc/motd", "r")

attempt to index global ''io''
```

Neither I can use a socket module:

```
[string "local s=require(''socket'');local t=assert(s.tc..."]:1: attempt to call global ''require''
```

Is it possible at all to read files and execute commands from inside Tarantool LUA console ?

Answer (score 0):

Lua is an [extensible, embeddable language](http://www.lua.org/about.html). There's no requirement that host programs using the language open the *standard libraries*. As such, not all programs utilizing Lua will open the [`io`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.8) or [`package`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.3) libraries. Instead, they may choose to implement, and subsequently open, their own libraries.

The Tarantool module you are looking for is [`fio`](https://tarantool.org/doc/reference/reference_lua/fio.html), and the similarly named [`fio.open`](https://tarantool.org/doc/reference/reference_lua/fio.html#lua-function.fio.open).

```
file_handle = fio.open('/etc/motd', { 'O_RDONLY' })
```

Note that Tarantool has a built-in [`socket`](https://tarantool.org/doc/reference/reference_lua/socket.html) module, as well.

---

Sources:

- [Tarantool Documentation](https://tarantool.org/doc/)
- [Tarantool Reference Manual](https://tarantool.org/doc/reference/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, but this does not seem to be a working solution - lua file_handle = fio.open('/etc/motd', { 'O_RDONLY' })
---
error: '[string "file_handle = fio.open(''/etc/motd'', { ''O_RDON..."]:1: attempt to index global ''fio'' (a nil value)'

Comment: Close but no cigar( attempt to index global ''fio'' (a nil value)'

Comment: @AlehBoitsau Yeah, it looks as though I'm slightly mistaken. It seems as though they do open standard libs, and as such you need to use `require` to open their modules - but your instance of `tarantool` doesn't appear to have any standard libs. Perhaps you should update your question with your Tarantool version / operating system, and how you built and installed the program.

Comment: @AlehBoitsau Also, `tarantool -h <host> -a <port>` doesn't seem to be valid in versions 1.6 or 1.7. Playing around in my environment, I use the sister application `tarantoolctl` to connect to an application server, and I don't prefix Lua code with `lua`. Note however, that I've never used this program before today. Maybe our configurations are wildly different.